# is it bad practice to use app.quit() to close all open windows in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an Electron app with NodeJS and Express.  I have the main process code in one file (app.js) and the routes in another file (router.js).

The main file creates the main window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1280, height: 800, icon: iconPath});
```

The routes file creates a new window whenever you click on a pdf document link in the application:

```
 router.get('/docs/:module/:type/:file', function(req, res) {
  openPDF(req.params.module,req.params.type,req.params.file);
  res.end();
});

// open pdf's in a new window
let newWindow;
const openPDF = function(module,filetype,filename) {

  let file = 'file:///' + __dirname + '/app/docs/' + module + '/' + filetype + '/' + filename;

  let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    icon: iconPath,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    }
  });

  newWindow.setMenu(null);
  // newWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  const param = qs.stringify({file: file});

  newWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?' + param);

  newWindow.on('closed', function() {
    newWindow = null;
  });
}
```

When I close the main window I want any other open windows to close as well.  I have been having a difficult time trying to implement this (both windows are in the main process so I can't use IPC to the best of my knowledge.)  Then I realized that if I call app.quit() when the main window closes it closes all of the other windows:

```
// Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
    // quitting the app on main window close will close any other open windows
    app.quit();
  })
```

My question is whether or not this is a bad thing to do.  It does terminate all open windows without any user input, but there is no unsaved work that could be lost since all of the new windows would be pdf's which can not be edited.

Comment: If the answer below helped you out, please make sure to upvote/accept it to help other's who may have the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using a state container framework like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), or [Flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux) to manage closing. This way, when you recieve the close signal from the user, you can dispatch a signal to make sure to:

- Prompt the user if their data is unsaved
- Buffer the config data of the app to a file, if you'd like (*to resume from previous state on next start*)
- Then run `app.quit()` so you can ensure a safe exit

Other than that, if your app requires no safe-close, then `app.quit` by itself is a perfectly fine way of closing your electron app.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

First, you say "both windows are in the main process so I can't use IPC to the best of my knowledge."  Actually, this is not true. Using `BrowserWindow` itself launches another process. In the Electron ecosystem (which is really the Node environment with Electron shell UI and API add-ons) when you spawn BrowserWindow's you are creating new render processes and each of those render processes have IPC channels available to both the main and render processes to access one another.

Second, you ask about using the `app.quit()` on the `'close'` event on the mainWindow ("*My question is whether or not this is a bad thing to do.*").  This is fine to do, as you say, as long as you aren't worried about cleaning up any data in the window/process. Even if you did have to clean something up, you could handle it in that `'close'` event function. So, don't worry, it is not a bad thing to do.

Comment: When I try to use Renderer on the new window I get an error about the module being undefined.  I read somewhere else that is because Renderer is not available on the main process.  This is also why I use the term "to the best of my knowledge".  I'm still new at this!